# Comment shape changes in excel when I edit the excel and reopen it again from rectangle to arrow

Tags: java, excel

I am creating an excel using Apache POI with the cells having comments in it and I am protecting the sheet after that. When I download the excel and edit the excel and if I reopen it again the comment box shape changes from rectangle to some arrow shape but when I open the excel for the first time , it is in rectangular shape.

What is a good solution for this?

Example images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apparently this is [a known bug](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/comment-boxes-changing-shape-by-themselves/db78c2e1-756a-48f9-ba30-ab062993a0ab) in Excel

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens in older version of Apache Poi which version 3.6 . It is not happening in latest version of poi. so try using the latest version.